# Replacing the apache it works page with the alfresco login page

Tags: apache, alfresco

I am using apache as the proxy for tomcat and I am able to remove the port number from the url (after reading so many post from stack overflow).

Now I need to replace the apache `it works` page with the alfresco login page. Here is what I did.

I removed the index.html file from the `htdocs` folder
I copied the index.jsp file from the alfresco folder
I modified httpd.conf file as below

```
<Directory "C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco">
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.jsp
</IfModule
```

But I am getting the text format of index.jsp file (just like in notepad) instead of the login page. What is the problem?

**UPDATED**

I used mod rewrite to do this

Comment: You need to use Tomcat to render a .jsp, Apache HTTPD can't process a JSP = Java Servlet Page

Comment: `<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.05; URL=/alfresco"></html>` 
I added this in index.html file of apache so it redirects. Is it correct to do so? Any other way?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is quite a common solution